# Gitlab-CI: Run deployment stage after merge with reference to source branch

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have n features branch that will MR and merge into a `develop` branch.

I have a pipeline with 3 stages:

`stages:
  - feature-push
  - develop-mr-retag
  - develop-mr-rollout`

`feature-push` runs on any push to a feature branch (not the `develop` branch we are merging into). It will test, build, and push an app in a docker image **tagged with the name of the feature branch**.

The latter two stages should run on commits to a branch `develop` after a merge request is approved and merged (assuming the source branch passed the feature-push stage). It needs to rollout the new image to some k8s pods, and it needs the name of the source branch to find the correct image.

I want to use `${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}` for this, but I don't think that variable exists for pipelines run after a merge, only on `merge_requests` pipelines. These seem to be triggered before an MR is approved, which I don't want as this is a deployment.

Is this possible or should I find a different approach?

**Edit: ** To clarify, I need to run my docker build before MR, to know it can build successfully. I don't want to just throw away that build if it's the one that gets merged, so that's why I want to build/push before MR, and deploy the previously built image after MR.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same.

For the moment, I parse the commit title of the mergecommit to extract the source branch, and I check that the branch found really exist. Here is the relevant code :

```
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME=$(sed -r "s/^Merge branch '(.*)' into .*/\1/i"<<<$CI_COMMIT_TITLE)

if [ $(git ls-remote --heads ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL} $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME | wc -l ) -ne 1 ]; then echo "Can't find source branche ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME})" && exit 1; fi
```

But if the default commit title is modified by anybody, this will not work.

Comment: This is something I considered but didn’t like it. For now I just build and throw away the container, then build again and push/deploy after merge. To save a bit of time I only run tests on the pre-merge stage.